# Rails not loading mountable engine's js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I have a mountable rails engine included in `Gemfile` as

```
gem 'my_engine', :path => 'engines/my_engine'
```

and mounting in main app as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount MyEngine::Engine => "/blog", as: 'blog_engine'
end
```

In `app/engines/my_engine/app/assets/javascripts/my_engine/application.js` I have

```
alert('hello');
```

In `app/engines/my_engine/lib/my_engine/engine.rb` I added

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    # Append engine's migrations to root app's migrations
    initializer :append_migrations do |app|
      unless app.root.to_s.match root.to_s
        config.paths["db/migrate"].expanded.each do |expanded_path|
          app.config.paths["db/migrate"] << expanded_path
        end
      end
    end

    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/spec/support"]

    initializer "my_engine.precompile" do |app|
      app.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('/engines/my_engine/app/assets/javascripts')
      app.config.assets.precompile << "my_engine/application.js"
    end

  end
end
```

But when I reload `http://localhost:3000/blog` alert message is not showing up? What am I missing ?

Comment: You're setup seems correct for the engine. Can you post how you're calling the alert? The problem may be in the way of your alert call. I'm assuming that, after you setup the engine and added it to the Gemfile you have run ```bundle install```, right?

Comment: Allam Matsubara Yes thats right, I ran bundle install after specifying the engine in gemfile

Comment: And your alert call?

Comment: @AllamMatsubara as I mentioned in the question in application.js I added the alert call, it should show up when I load /blog route right?

Comment: It won't unless you have wrapped it in something that is triggered when the page loads, for example, if you're using jquery:

    $(document).ready( function() {
      alert('hello');
    });

This will trigger after every page loads in your app, but it'll will show you that you're engine is fine.

Answer (score 6):

You also need to actually insert the JavaScript into your page. Do you have a `javascript_include_tag` pulling in the `application.js` file in your blog code? It often gets put into one of the layouts:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'my_engine/application' %>
```